# Is it possible to modify the default YouTube embed attributes string?

Tags: embed, youtube

I'd like to suppress related YouTube videos by appending '&rel=0' to the string of embed attributes output to the video iframe in my post.

I believe this requires a filter that modifies the $attr array before it is passed to wp_embed_handler_youtube() (located in wp-includes/media.php).

Assuming I'm on the right track, is there a way to add a filter to my child theme to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

Ok, so I'm still pretty lost...  here is the code in my functions.php:

```
function modify_YT_embed_attributes($embed, $attr, $url, $rawattr) {  
    $attr["rel"] = "0"; //modify the attributes array
    return $embed; 
}    
add_filter('wp_embed_handler_youtube', 'modify_YT_embed_attributes', 10, 4);
```

Still not working. What is the obvious thing I'm missing?

Comment: as you see the file media.php, you can use the filter `wp_embed_handler_youtube`

Comment: Thanks mmm, for your speedy reply.  I suspected it was indeed possible. However in this case I can't find any relevant examples of the code I might use in my child theme functions.php to accomplish the change.
Can you help get me started?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is a filter with the same name as the function `wp_embed_handler_youtube`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_embed_handler_youtube/

```
add_filter('wp_embed_handler_youtube', 'ehy_callback', 10, 4);

function ehy_callback($embed, $attr, $url, $rawattr){

   //make necessary changes here
   return $embed;
}
```

You can add the code in `functions.php` of your child theme.

Comment: this filter returns is applied on the HTML code. so you have to return the result of the callback in `$embed`. look the content of the 4 arguments to help you

Comment: @WisdmLabs Thanks for the code example. I'm puzzled tho. In this case I'll be modifying $attr. Wouldn't I return that parameter instead? Thanks in advance for your clarification.

Comment: @mmm I looked, and I'm still awash in the fog of my own ignorance... :) If you had a look at my code above and could help out, I'd sure appreciate it!

Comment: can you try printing `$embed` and see if you can include necessary parameter into that. If the output is not being printed, just log it in DB and check the result.