# How to add srcdoc attribute to YouTube oEmbed in Gutenberg oEmbed Block

Tags: block-editor, oembed, youtube

First of all, let me mention that I have already looked at the following two similar questions:

- [Is it possible to modify the default YouTube embed attributes string?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199558/is-it-possible-to-modify-the-default-youtube-embed-attributes-string)
- [Filter oembeds tags to modify iframe attributes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320080/filter-oembeds-tags-to-modify-iframe-attributes)

But both of them are pre Gutenberg era. So, while using Gutenberg oEmbed block to embed a YouTube video if I want to add a `srcdoc` attribute to it, is there a way to do it? Or do I have to create my custom block for it? I'm really confused here about whether or not the `wp_embed_handler_youtube` or `embed_oembed_html` filters will help me here.

#### Current Embedding Sutuation

So, currently when you use Gutenberg oEmbed block to embed a YouTube video, it basically adds the following `iframe`:

```html
<iframe 
loading="lazy" 
title="Some Title" 
width="680" 
height="383" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<VIDEO_ID>?feature=oembed" 
frameborder="0" 
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Which is wrapped withing a few HTML element added by WP  Core.

#### What I am looking for

What I am looking for here is to add the `srcdoc` attribute to that YouTube embeds to better lazy load the video. So, it would become something like:

```html
<iframe 
width="560" 
height="315" 
loading="lazy" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<VIDEO_ID>" 
srcdoc="<style>*{padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden}html,body{height:100%}img,span{position:absolute;width:100%;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto}span{height:1.5em;text-align:center;font:48px/1.5 sans-serif;color:white;text-shadow:0 0 0.5em black}</style><a href=https://www.youtube.com/embed/<VIDEO_ID>?autoplay=1><img src=https://img.youtube.com/vi/<VIDEO_ID>/maxresdefault.jpg alt='Types of Succulents -- Cold Hardy and Soft Succulents'><span>▶</span></a>" 
title="Types of Succulents -- Cold Hardy and Soft Succulents" 
frameborder="0" 
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Does anyone have any idea about how to accomplish this while using Gutenberg oEmbed Block to embed the YouTube video? Any suggestions and help are very welcome.

Comment: Have you tried either of the filters you mentioned yet? They apply when WordPress gets the iframe source from YouTube using the URL, and should run regardless of which editor you’re using.

Comment: @JacobPeattie No. But in that case, I need to ask if I choose to use the `wp_embed_handler_youtube` filter. Is there a way to get the Video ID? Or do I have to write my own RegEx to parse the URL and get the Video ID out of it? That was my second question in case any of those above methods works.

Comment: The gutenberg embed blocks just fetch HTML via the REST API and act as a preview box. They aren't responsible for creating the HTML you are seeing. You can do this without ever touching gutenberg or JS. Look at the oembed PHP filters